# Pending sector count went down to zero without being reallocated?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, smart, smartd

A week ago I had a `smartctl` alert saying that the Current Pending Sector count went up to 1. The alert had repeated for 4 days, and stopped.

I was expecting for the sector to become reallocated, but in fact now both Current Pending Sector, Reallocated Sector, and Reallocated Event counts are zero! How could this be and what does this mean?

Disk in question is a year-old WD Caviar Green in a USB enclosure attached to a NAS. The disk is persistently monitored by `smartd`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you to backup the files from that WD Green somewhere else, @Leonid, and keep monitoring the S.M.A.R.T. data of the HDD. The Current Pending Sector Count indicates the count of unstable sectors *(waiting for remapping)*. Later, when some of these sectors are read successfully, the raw value decreases.  If the errors still occur when reading some sector, the hard drive will try to restore the data, by transfer it to the reserved disk area (spare sectors) and mark this sector as remapped *(a.k.a. as bad sectors)*. These sectors are listed in the Reallocated Sector Count of the S.M.A.R.T attributes.

The best way to prevent any potential data loss is to always have, at least, two copies of your files stored on different storage devices/locations. If, by any chance, these critical parameters increase, make sure you [check the WD Green's warranty](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=sHRdwN) and contact our [Customer Support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=CUyljs).

Good luck! Hope I was helpful! :)